# Sending data to a django using chrome runtime sendMessage

Tags: django, google-chrome

I have a django server running and I have a chrome extension, from  extension I want to send some data to server but I am getting undefined as return. Here is what I am trying.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: 'POST',
        action: 'xmlrpc',
        url: 'http://localhost/send',
        data: info.selectionText
    }, function(responseText) {
        alert(responseText);
    });
```

I am not sure what I am missing, any hints ?

Comment: A first place to look would be

`url: 'http://localhost/send',` has no port (Localhost needs a port). Try `url: 'http://localhost:8000/send',` where 8000 is the port you use

Comment: tried that, effect is same ..